# Fetch with Axios and React-Redux

Tags: react-redux, axios

I am using **axios** in my **react-redux** app. This is my API call:

let array = [];
let array2 = [1,2,3];

```
            for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
                array.push(axios.get(`https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=${array2[i]}`))

            }

            const array3 = axios.all(array).then(response);
```

If I do the console.log of **response** into then(), I get the desired result (Array[5]), but if I do the console.log of **array3**, the output is:

*Promise
  **proto** : Promise
  [[PromiseStatus]] : "resolved"
  [[PromiseValue]] : Array[5]*

How can I extract the informations of the array contained into [[PromiseValue]] and to put them into another array? Until now I have experience only with React, but I have no idea how can I treat data of parallel fetchs with react-redux. 
Thank you in anticipation!

Comment: `axios` returns a Promise and that's what you're getting. You need to handle that Promise with `.then()` and `.catch()`

Comment: Gracias! Thank you so much! I have found the solution, which I will write below in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:
delete the last line of the code ( const array3 = axios.all(array).then(response); )  and write:

const array3 = [ ]

axios.all(array).then(response => array3.push(response.map( (d, index) => d.data)));